# Array won't appear in JTable

Tags: java, arrays, swing, intellij-idea, jtable

Using IntelliJ IDEA, I used the Swing UI Designer to design a program that would display student information through a table. The problem is that the data won't appear on my JTable. What I did was first read the information from a file to an ArrayList and then to make it appear on the JTable I put all the information from the ArrayList to a multidimensional array. I tried testing it on a separate program and the elements are there. It just won't appear on my JTable for this program.

```java
Object[][] data = new Object[listOfCourses.size()][5];
for (int i = 0; i < listOfCourses.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
        data[i][j] = yearInWord(listOfCourses.get(i).getYear());
        for (int k = 1; k < 2; k++) {
            data[i][k] = termInWord(listOfCourses.get(i).getTerm());
            for (int l = 2; l < 3; l++) {
                data[i][l] = listOfCourses.get(i).getCourseCode();
                for (int m = 3; m < 4; m++) {
                    data[i][m] = listOfCourses.get(i).getCourseName();
                    for (int n = 4; n < 5; n++) {
                        data[i][n] = listOfCourses.get(i).getUnits();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```java
courseTable.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(data, new String[]{"Year", "Term", "Course No.", "Course Title", "Units"}));
```

I have tried checking if the elements of the array are read by using println in another program. So the elements are in the array but they just won't appear in my JTable. I have also tried manually making an array such as

```java
Object[][] trial = {
    { yearInWord(1), termInWord(1), "CFE 101", "GOD'S JOURNEY WITH HIS PEOPLE", 3 },
    { yearInWord(1), termInWord(2), "CFE 102", "CHRISTIAN MORALITY IN OUR TIMES", 2 },
    { yearInWord(1), termInWord(3), "CFE 103", "CATHOLIC FOUNDATION OF MISSION", 1 }
};
```

and then replacing data with trial in the setModel line of code then it was able to show the contents of the trial array. Since there are many Courses in my listOfCourses, I can't just manually encode each of them.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the logic, it does not appear that you'll need the nested for-loops.  Each subsequent loop is only iterating once.

Comment: *I first read the information from a file to an ArrayList*  - The DefaultTableModel use a Vector of Vectors to hold the data. So currently your code would have 3 references to the data: 1) the ArrayList, 2) the Array and 3) the Vectors. No need for 3 copies. Instead, create a custom `CourseTableModel` that uses the ArrayList to hold the data. See the example from [Row Table Model](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) on how to create the custom model.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the nested for-loops.

What you can do is iterate once, for each item in `listOfCourses`, setting each secondary index to the according column.

I changed `i` to `row` for clarity.

```java
Object[][] data = new Object[listOfCourses.size()][5];
for (int row = 0; row < listOfCourses.size(); row++) {
    data[row][0] = yearInWord(listOfCourses.get(row).getYear());
    data[row][1] = termInWord(listOfCourses.get(row).getTerm());
    data[row][2] = listOfCourses.get(row).getCourseCode();
    data[row][3] = listOfCourses.get(row).getCourseName();
    data[row][4] = listOfCourses.get(row).getUnits();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've reproduce your code as I understood like this:

```
package answer;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class MyAnswer extends JFrame {

    public MyAnswer() {
        super("Stackoverflow answer");
        WindowListener l = new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        };

        getContentPane()
                .add(createTable());

        addWindowListener(l);
        setSize(800, 800);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public JTable createTable() {
        final List<Course> listOfCourses = getCourses();
        Object[][] data = new Object[listOfCourses.size()][5];
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfCourses.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
                data[i][j] = yearInWord(listOfCourses.get(i).getYear());
                for (int k = 1; k < 2; k++) {
                    data[i][k] = termInWord(listOfCourses.get(i).getTerm());
                    for (int l = 2; l < 3; l++) {
                        data[i][l] = listOfCourses.get(i).getCourseCode();
                        for (int m = 3; m < 4; m++) {
                            data[i][m] = listOfCourses.get(i).getCourseName();
                            for (int n = 4; n < 5; n++) {
                                data[i][n] = listOfCourses.get(i).getUnits();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        JTable myTable = new JTable(
                new DefaultTableModel(data, new String[] { "Year", "Term", "Course No.", "Course Title", "Units" }));
        myTable.setSize(700, 400);
        return myTable;
    }

    private String yearInWord(int year) {
        return year + "";
    }

    private String termInWord(int term) {
        return term + "";
    }

    public List<Course> getCourses() {
        final List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<>();
        courses.add(new Course(1, 1, "CFE 101", "GOD'S JOURNEY WITH HIS PEOPLE", 3));
        courses.add(new Course(1, 2, "CFE 102", "CHRISTIAN MORALITY IN OUR TIMES", 2));
        courses.add(new Course(1, 3, "CFE 102", "CATHOLIC FOUNDATION OF MISSION", 1));
        return courses;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyAnswer();
    }
}
```

And **Course** class is like this:

```
package answer;

public class Course {
    private final int year;
    private final int term;
    private final String courseCode;
    private final String courseName;
    private final int units;

    public Course(int year, int term, String courseCode, String courseName, int units) {
        this.year = year;
        this.term = term;
        this.courseCode = courseCode;
        this.courseName = courseName;
        this.units = units;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public int getTerm() {
        return term;
    }

    public String getCourseCode() {
        return courseCode;
    }

    public String getCourseName() {
        return courseName;
    }

    public int getUnits() {
        return units;
    }
    
    public Object[] getDefaultModel() {
        return new String[] {
            this.year + "",
            this.term + "",
            this.courseCode,
            this.courseCode,
            this.units + ""
        };
    }
}
```

So, I've the result as expected:
[image: my answer screenshoot]

To debug your code, please let us know all your code. How you read the file? How your course class look like? Can you upload your file content?

Anyway, your code need to be refactored. All nested loop is not necessary because your loop step is always 1. Then, your code should be like:

```
Object[][] data = new Object[listOfCourses.size()][5];
for (int row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
    data[row][0] = yearInWord(listOfCourses.get(row).getYear());
    data[row][1] = termInWord(listOfCourses.get(row).getTerm());
    data[row][2] = listOfCourses.get(row).getCourseCode();
    data[row][3] = listOfCourses.get(row).getCourseName();
    data[row][4] = listOfCourses.get(row).getUnits();
}
```

Comment: Hey, that's my for-loop re-write!  I'm just kidding, glad it helped.